# React Native webview closes when app goes to background in android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

Hi have an app which opens a webview which works completly fine. I am facing problem when app goes to background it closes the webview and displays the landing screen. I am trying to find a way where I can prevent the app from closing webview in react native. I am using `react-native-webview`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this flags when you open the browser in RN code:

```
const options = { forceCloseOnRedirection: false, showInRecents: true };
await InAppBrowser.open(url, options);
```